# How to find out Database calls triggered by a specific IIS request

Tags: sql-server, performance, iis, logging, sql-server-profiler

Is there any way to  find out Database calls triggered by a specific IIS request ?

I have IIS Logs, which I am parsing using IIS Log Parser tool.
I am trying to create a tool, which can list number of database calls, made by a specific request of IIS.

Is there any way or any tool , which can help me achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two evident posibilities:

1. Tracing ADO.NET drivers. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421.aspx)
2. Tracing SQL Server (through SQL Profiler).

Could you explain why they are not suitable in your case?